# why do we Carbonate drinks not any other gas

Tags: everyday-life, physical-chemistry

Carbonation is done in all fizzy drinks. Also it forms a small amount of carbonic acid which we feel on our tongue. We can diffuse oxygen as well in the water at higher level. Except for acid formation is there any other reason we don't use any other gas other than $CO_2$?

Comment: Some beverages use nitrogen: http://www.craftbeer.com/craft-beer-muses/good-beer-gas-nitro-beers-explained

Comment: This might be a better question for chemistry stackexchange

Comment: What else is there that's cheap, non-toxic, dissolves well in water but still fizzes out a bit, and mildly acidic?  What would you prefer?  Amonia, chlorine, hydrogen sulphide, cyanide?

Comment: Ask the fermentation bacteria.  They started the practice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that this might be better for chemistry stackexchange. However I will give you an short answer after doing a little searching. You should look at [Henry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry%27s_law) which states that that the concentration, $c$, of a gas in a liquid at a specific temperature is proportional to the partial pressure, $p$, of that gas in the atmosphere above the liquid,
$$
p=k_Hc.
$$
So the concentration will be the higher if $k_H$ is smaller.

Wikipedia also gives a table for a few common gasses of these $k_H$ constants at room temperature $(298.15 K)$. For $CO_2$ it is equal to $29.41\frac{atm}{mol/L}$. However the constant of $O_2$ is equal to $769.23\frac{atm}{mol/L}$, so you would need roughly 26 times higher partial pressure of $O_2$ to get the same concentration. And for nitrogen it is even roughly 56 times higher $(k_{H,N_2}=1639.34\frac{atm}{mol/L})$.

I do not know how many other gasses also have a relatively low Henry's law constant, $k_H$. But I believe, if I did the conversion correctly, that ammonia has an even lower value of roughly (the [literature values](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7664417&Mask=10) deviate quite a bit) $0.02\frac{atm}{mol/L}$.

**Edit:**
Apparently ozonated water is being used [medically](http://www.ehow.com/about_5470890_drink-ozonated-water.html). Ozone has a [Henry's law constant](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C10028156&Mask=10) of about $100.30\frac{atm}{mol/L}$, so it will escape the water eventually and therefore it has to be [made before consumption](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-bdhv4kCf8). But I was not able to find a source that ozonated water is fizzy, so I do not know why it does for $CO_2$, it probably has something to do with the fact that it also forms carbonic acid.

Comment: Not sure that fizzy ammonia soft drinks are going to catch on

Comment: Chlorine dissolves well in water too. How about methane hydrides?

Comment: probably, $CO_2$ doesn't alter the taste (compared to $Cl$), color and mostly harmless compared to $NH_3$.